# Do we need to reboot Apache web server if we update the source code of website it is hosting?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Well I am not an expert on Apache or any web server,  I have recently finished my first web app,  so I have rsyncd code to web server /HTML.
The web app is python flask based uses wsgi module to load.

I do not have control over Apache as it's taken care by systems department.

So I cannot test myself in office.  I just want to know if we upload updated/modified code to the host machine running apache web server,  will it pick up changes or we need to restart the Apache web server?

Comment: There are circumstances where Apache might be required, but there are also times restarting Apache would not be needed. To be safe, I would suggest restarting Apache for a Python/Flask app.

Comment: I too thought the same,  make sense.. If a company is running lots of web apps serving different departments that would mean that many physical host machine or VM running there on web server?  And an reverse proxy server to put them under one domain name different URL or port?

Comment: Python is interpreted. so if the request gets to it, will be executed then and there.  So if you change the code, the next execution will use it.